# How can I avoid repeated code using lambdas?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a method which should accept a Function/Action and do something with that method (in my case I've added retry logic).

I'm wondering how I can remove the duplicated code (for loop, etc) from the last 2 methods. Is there any clever way to do this in C#?

```
public static class Retry {
    public static void Do(
    Type retryOnExceptionType,
    Action action,
    TimeSpan retryInterval =
    default (TimeSpan),
    int retryCount = 3) {
        if (retryInterval ==
        default (TimeSpan)) retryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        Do < object > (
        retryOnExceptionType, () = > {
            action();
            return null;
        }, retryInterval, retryCount);
    }

    public static T1 Do < T1, T2, T3 > (
    Type retryOnExceptionType,
    Func < T2, T3, T1 > action,
    T2 param1,
    T3 param2,
    TimeSpan retryInterval =
    default (TimeSpan),
    int retryCount = 3) {
        if (retryInterval ==
        default (TimeSpan)) retryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        var exceptions = new List < Exception > ();

        for (int retry = 0; retry < retryCount; retry++) {
            try {
                return action(param1, param2);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                if (!retryOnExceptionType.IsInstanceOfType(ex)) throw;

                exceptions.Add(ex);
                Thread.Sleep(retryInterval);
            }
        }

        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }


    public static T Do < T > (
    Type retryOnExceptionType,
    Func < T > action,
    TimeSpan retryInterval =
    default (TimeSpan),
    int retryCount = 3) {
        if (retryInterval ==
        default (TimeSpan)) retryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        var exceptions = new List < Exception > ();

        for (int retry = 0; retry < retryCount; retry++) {
            try {
                return action();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                if (!retryOnExceptionType.IsInstanceOfType(ex)) throw;

                exceptions.Add(ex);
                Thread.Sleep(retryInterval);
            }
        }

        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code indentaton is horribly non-standard and hard to read. :(

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to wrap up your loops in a single method that takes a `Func<T>` and then do something like this:

```
public static T1 Do<T1,T2,T3>(Type retryOnExceptionType, Func<T2,T3,T1> action, T2 param1,
                              T3 param2, TimeSpan retryInterval, int retryCount)
{
    var del = new Func<T1>(() => action(param1, param2));
    return DoLoops<T1>(del, retryOnExceptionType, retryInterval, retryCount);
}


public static T Do<T>(Type retryOnExceptionType, Func<T> action,TimeSpan retryInterval,
                      int retryCount)
{
    return DoLoops<T>(action, retryOnExceptionType, retryInterval, retryCount);
}

private static T DoLoops<T>(Func<T> func, Type retryOnExceptionType,
                            TimeSpan retryInterval, int retryCount)
{
    if (retryInterval == default(TimeSpan))
        retryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

    var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

    for (int retry = 0; retry < retryCount; retry++)
    {
        try
        {
            return func();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (!retryOnExceptionType.IsInstanceOfType(ex))
                throw;

            exceptions.Add(ex);
            Thread.Sleep(retryInterval);
        }
    }

    throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
}
```

The key is in wrapping up your `Func<T2, T3, T1>` call in a separate `Func<T1>`, which allows you to pass a parameterless delegate to `DoLoops` regardless of how many type parameters the original delegate has, since that's the only difference between the original methods.

Even simpler, you can do away with `DoLoops` and just keep the `for` loop in the `public static T Do<T>` overload and `Do<T1, T2, T3>` can just pass the parameterless delegate it creates into that method:

```
public static T1 Do<T1,T2,T3>(Type retryOnExceptionType, Func<T2,T3,T1> action, T2 param1,
                              T3 param2, TimeSpan retryInterval, int retryCount)
{
    return Do<T1>(retryOnExceptionType, () => action(param1, param2),
                  retryInterval, retryCount);
}


public static T Do<T>(Type retryOnExceptionType, Func<T> action, TimeSpan retryInterval,
                      int retryCount)
{
    if (retryInterval == default(TimeSpan))
        retryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

    var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

    for (int retry = 0; retry < retryCount; retry++)
    {
        try
        {
            return action();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (!retryOnExceptionType.IsInstanceOfType(ex))
                throw;

            exceptions.Add(ex);
            Thread.Sleep(retryInterval);
        }
    }

    throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
}
```

Comment: Yea this is amazing!